# How to disable the Tv remote only right navigation focus using js-spatial-navigation on Webos?

Tags: webos

"I am trying to implement **https://github.com/luke-chang/js-spatial-navigation**   on  the webos multiple lists if one list is finsihed after i click on the TV remote right navigation the foucs is going to next list but i want to stop the right focus on once user reaches the last item of the list but it should work on left and top and bottom focus"

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want to achieve, i.e. with a picture or fiddle. I too use `js-spatial-navigation`, but can't figure out what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problem either. From my experience the horizontal row is limited by the TV screen width and once you hit the last item in the row the right arrow keys doesn't work, but I'm not familiar with webos. I've had good success adding fading context text that appear when a item is focused and a changing hero graphic too. Check out http://loopzine.tv/firetv.htm
D-pad or keyboard with arrow keys required.